# How to Make Preset Unique Class Objects

Tags: java, class, oop, object, colors

So when you're using graphics and you need to define a color, you can write the color as its RGB value with the 3 int values or you can also just type Color newColor = **Color.Red** or Color newColor = **Color.Blue** to define it as the preset pure color.

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this and how I would go about doing it in a class that I've created myself so I could define things with only that one object or use only that as the parameter.

Like if I made a Person class and then in another class i had a method that used a Person as the parameter, i could just say **Person.Teacher** and it would know the general preset variables for that person. Sorry if thats a bad example but yeah how would i store that info in the person class

Comment: simple, not always best: `public static final Person TEACHER = new Person(..);`

Comment: no sorry i know that can be done but i was curious about the way its used for colors if that could be done without making an actual object

Comment: You must create an object.

Comment: Maybe you could use a constructor of an inner class that sets the variables, but it would look like `Person pers = new Person.Teacher();`, which is not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: sorry me, don't inderstand you... it is done exactly that way with colors, check the source code of Color: `public final static Color white     = new Color(255, 255, 255);` (it is an actual (instance of) object)and, BTW, `Color.Red` will not work with `java.awt.Color`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can know how they did it by looking at how `java.awt.Color.red` is defined:

```
public final static Color red       = new Color(255, 0, 0);
```

So you can define a person like this as well. You can just write this inside your `Person` class.

```
public final static Person TEACHER = new Person("John Smith", 29);
```

One thing to note is the type must be *immutable* for this to work well, otherwise you could do:

```
Person.TEACHER.setAge(100);
```

Which destroys the whole point of this pattern - to have constant values of `Person`.

Comment: maybe be it should be noted that this is a field of the Person (or Color) class, that is, this statement goes inside the given class - seems like the author of the question is not underestanding that...

Comment: and a bit more: you could override the `setAge` method in `TEACHER` (anonymous class extending Person) so it does not allowed changing the age... but not sure if I do like that, as you wrote, the type should be immutable!

Answer (score 1):

We can use enums for the required purpose.
A sample colour enum could be like:

```
public enum Colour {

    RED(255,0,0),
    BLUE(255,255,0);

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    private Colour(int a, int b, int c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }

}
```

Later, you can use the emun as:

```
Colour colour = Colour.RED;
```

Comment: how can you create a new color, one that is not listed in the enumeration? (all that setters are very strange, you really want a color to be changed after creation? so I can change RED to green!)

Comment: Got your point for the setters. Editing my answer accordingly. However, I am not sure if new colours would be required.

Comment: I doubt new colors (or persons) will **not** be needed. Enumeration is not very appropriate for representing colors or persons...

Answer (score -1):

Tried and tested. 100% works and outputs the color. No need to "extend" Colors. Use intellij, `alt+enter`, DONE.

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color thisWorks = RGBColors.RED.getColor();
        System.out.println(thisWorks);
    }


}
enum RGBColors{
    RED(new Color(255, 0, 0)),
    GREEN(new Color(0, 255, 0)),
    BLUE(new Color(0, 0, 255));

    Color color;

    Color getColor(){
        return color;
    }

    RGBColors(Color a) {
        color = a;
        //do something
    }
}
```